# CloudFoundry deployment: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase

Tags: java, deployment, cloud-foundry

I am deploying an executable jar file but keep getting the app staging buildpack error. I see my JavaMain is coming back as nil when I have a java_main.yml file saved in my config/ folder.

```
---
java_main_class:com.rft.rfda.gaia.Launcher
arguments:201610 2016 10 1 2500
```

Example output:

```
2017-05-12T16:55:51.11-0400 [STG/0] ERR [ConfigurationUtils] DEBUG Configuration from /var/vcap/data/deanext/adminbuildpacks/4dc31dfa-b83a-4f54-a7c5-123bf8b43ec373d57decf22d07d3d78e63a5797feb6c7ad97083/config/javamain.yml: {"javamainclass"=>nil, "arguments"=>nil}
```

I am pushing my application as below:

```
cf push gaia-bbrm-poc -p ./ -c "/bin/java -cp ./target/GAIAPOC-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.rft.rfda.gaia.Launcher" -b java_buildpack --no-route
```

Any input would be appreciated?

Comment: Have you tried with --random-route in place of --no-route?

Comment: Where is your `config/` folder & the `java_main.yml` file?  You wouldn't normally do this unless you've forked the build pack and are updating those files in the build pack (the Java build pack doesn't look at config in your app).  The correct way to customize config of the build pack in v3 is to use the `JBP_*` env variables -> https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/tree/3.x#configuration-and-extension.  Ex: `cf set-env my-application JBP_CONFIG_JAVA_MAIN '{java_main_class: com.my.main.Class}'`.

Comment: You also do not want to use `cf push -c` with the Java build pack, you should let it configure the startup command.  Using `-c` will completely override what the Java build pack is trying to do.  It also knows where to find things like the `java` binary, which is not on the path or in `/bin`.

Comment: My env for the app look like this: User-Provided:
JAVA_VERSION: 1.8.0_+
JBP_CONFIG_JAVA_MAIN: '{java_main_class:com.rft.rfda.gaia.Launcher}'

I am now executing with `I:\workspace\GAIAPOC>cf push gaia-bbrm-poc -p ./ -b java_buildpack --no-route`. Note: I am pushing from my app directory which has the jar in the target folder.

Got error: **[Buildpack]             ERROR Compile failed with exception #<RuntimeError: User configuration value is not valid: {java_main_class:com.rft.rfda.gaia.Launcher}>
User configuration value is not valid: {java_main_class:com.rft.rfda.gaia.Launcher}**

Comment: --random-route didn't work either but only because of the above error.